# Disable developer can merge in Gitlab project

Tags: gitlab

I'm using Gitlab. Project can be merged into master branch by Maintainer but Developer can though I set up allowed to merge is Maintainer. Now I want Developer can't allow to merge into master branch. Help me solve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have use the "[Allowed to merge](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#using-the-allowed-to-merge-and-allowed-to-push-settings)" setting, and a developer is still able to merge to the `master` branch, that means said developer has also the maintainer role.

Check that developer profile [for the permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html).